# Im trying to create a translator but i am getting a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

So I am trying to get this python to work but when I run it I get a syntax error after 'for space'.
I have tried putting a colon there but even when it is there it still says the same error.

```
with open("text.txt", "a") as save:
        dot = '\n' + x + ' ' + ' ' + entry.get() #For new line empty spaces
    for space
        save.write(dot)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I think you're confused between `for` and `if`.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Here's how a `for` statement is supposed to look: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to do a for loop. That's not the correct syntax.

I'd suggest going trough some basic tutorials first...! (Before coming on here and post basic problems with unclear code with an even unclearer thread title)

Here's a correct for loop:

```
data = [1,2,3,4]

for n in data:
    print n
```

Comment: I am trying to create a translator that has the option to add, remove and edit words in the program its self just by pressing the button, if you want I will post the code in its entirety so you can have a look

Comment: Like I said, I'd get the basics down first (if, for) before attempting the create an application.